# KnowledgeLake setup for MFP

Tags: scanning

I got following from web but dont know how to set up the network printer/scanner/fax/copier (using Ricoh Afico MP 6001) for KnowledgeLake. The capture server has been setup. \srvcapture\cache

Capture for MFP

- Create batches from multifunction peripherals, fax servers or any
  other interface.
- Enable any capture device to integrate with SharePoint
- Batch import documents from multi-function devices
- Watch network directories for new documents
- Distribute MFPs for decentralized scanning
- Support for custom Process Activities
- Enable off-hours batch processing by scheduling imports

Answer (score 0):

The particular information you are looking for can be found in the KnowledgeLake Capture and Capture Server documentation provided on the KnowledgeLake Support Portal at http://support.knowledgelake.com.

KnowledgeLake also has a Professional Services team that specializes in assisting in the implementation and setup of these products in customer environments.

The KnowledgeLake Technical Support team would also be more than happy to assist with any questions you may have if you put in a support ticket. This option is also available through the support portal at http://support.knowledgelake.com.

If you currently do not have an account with access to the KnowledgeLake Support Portal, you can select the "Request a New Account" button at the bottom of the previous referenced link.